# Using an iPhone as a source for a whole home audio system

Tags: audio

Not sure this is the correct StackExchange site, but I have a whole home audio system in my home. I have 2 Sonos units connected to it as sources, and they work fine. Is there a way to use my iPhone as a remote source for a whole home setup? Can't be bluetooth, and it would have to be a solution where I can remotely use my phone (on the same network is fine), but whatever is playing on my phone can be input to the preamp as a source.

I am thinking maybe there is some device you can buy that will "listen" to your phone and send the signal into the preamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sonos supports [Airplay](https://www.sonos.com/en-gb/airplay) so you should be able to just steam audio from the phone to the to that and have it feed into your existing system.